# Updating an existing entry in my database isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, foreign-keys, database-relations

I'm trying to use a list of clients that have been created from my client model in my new model called Jobs.

Basically. A user should be able to view a list of jobs that are currently assigned to any one client and then drill down into further information.

I have inserted a new column into my jobs database called client_id and have inserted the following code in my `_form` view to be able to see a drop down list of all the clients

```
<%= f.label :client_id %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :client_id, @clients, :id, :name, :prompt => 
    "Select" %>
```

However. When I hit submit it tries to POST it to `jobs/new` which according to my resource route. Doesn't exist.

I have also inserted some dummy data into the database and though that is showing up fine when I try to edit it. Pressing save will not do anything to the record.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0ZVYpM9vTgY+BI55Y9yJDwCJwrwSgGL9xjHq8dz5OBE=", "job"=>{"name"=>"Sample Monthly", "client_id"=>"2", "frequency"=>"Monthly", "owner"=>"Me"}, "commit"=>"Save Job", "id"=>"1"}
  Job Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE "jobs" SET "name" = 'Sample Monthly', "frequency" = 'Monthly', "updated_at" = '2012-05-12 17:04:23.818967' WHERE "jobs"."id" = 1
   (108.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/jobs/1
```

Here's my controller..

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_clients, :only => [ :new, :create, :edit ]

  def index
    @job = Job.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @Job }
    end
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(params[:job])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @job, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @job }
    end
  end

  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def load_clients
        @client = Client.find(:all)
    end
  end
```

I suppose to get this working is a relatively easy fix but this is my forst Rails app and i'm not sure where to start.

Edit:

As requested. Here is my jobs form:

```
<%= form_for(:job) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :client_id %><br />
     <%= f.collection_select :client_id, @client, :id, :name, :prompt => 
    "Select" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :frequency %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :frequency %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :owner %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :owner %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit2: Here's my Job model.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clients
end
```

Comment: need more info about your form

Comment: Added my jobs _form to the first post

Comment: Could you also update your question with the Job model source code? Do you use attr_accessible?

Comment: Done.

What does the attr_acessible method do?

Comment: attr_accessible specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment. http://bit.ly/KhZRC6 But I think it is not this case because you dont have an error with mass-assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace `:job` with `@job` in your form.

And also looks like you are missing `edit` action in your controller.

Comment: Editing is now working fine. However, when I now create a new job. All the details like name etc are saving EXCEPT the client details which although im specifying. Are coming out blank on the success screen.

Comment: you have wrong association replace `belongs_to :clients` with `belongs_to :client`

Comment: Making progress :-)

Im now succcesfully creating th job and the client is listed.. but it looks like it's coming out as a hash instead of the text value.

`Job was successfully created.
Job
Name:
Weekly test

Client:
**#<Client:0x000001018b08b0>**

Frequency:
Never

Owner:
Me`

Comment: I think thats not a problem with updating... But if you mean this `#<Client:0x000001018b08b0>` it is a client object and it is allright I think.

Comment: text value of what? if the client have a name you can call name method on that object `client.name`

Comment: Yes of course. Sorry for the confusion. I was already calling `@job.client` which I expected to give me the client name in it's text form. But its now @job.client.name and everything is fine. Thank you!